# How do i prove there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converging to limit superior?

Tags: real-analysis

How do i prove that, for a given sequence $x_n$ there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converging to $\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sup_{m>n} x_m$?

I know how to prove this, but my argument is not really basic. (I used induction repetitively and then get a subsequence in a diagonal term.)

I know there is a basic proof but i forgot..

Would someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s = \limsup \left\{x_n\right\}$. We know that for any $k < s$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$, there is an $n > N$ such that $x_n > k$, otherwise $s$ would not be the limsup.

However, that means that there are an infinite number of points of your sequence arbitrarily close to the limsup, so it is clear that there is a subsequence converging to it.

That's at least the idea behind it, although I wouldn't call it a proof. I'm in a bit of a rush, so if this didn't make sense I can provide clarification.